# 80's SciFi short-movie where the domestic devices come to life and takes over from humans

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots

I'm looking for a short movie, probably from the 80s, I remember having watched when I was a kid... It was on a VHS (yes, I'm started to be old already), a compilation of several "horror" short movies... One of them was about the Hiroshima story if I remember well, on the same VHS...

In that short movie, all I can remember is that at some point, some domestic devices came to life, and started a coordinated rebellion against humans... Probably they managed to modify themselves too because at some point, there was some kind of robotic spiders attacking a man (the main character) in some toilets...

Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: Note that those spiders might have inspired Stargate Replicators, because in my memories, they were very similar... But, Stargate didn't exist yet, for sure, and it really was a short movie (like ~20 min at max, something like that)

Comment: Ah, that's what the world is coming to with the Internet of Things.

Comment: ah ah, funny comment :)

Comment: Och... and I just now see that someone mentioned Runaway already. Ah well, I'll let my answer ride in case someone else is looking for a robot spider movie.

Comment: no prob guys, thanks for the suggestion anyway @FuzzyBoots

Answer (score 11):

Robot spiders and rogue appliances brings to mind *[Runaway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runaway_(1984_film))*, a 1984 Tom Selleck vehicle where he is part of a police division that deals with malfunctioning robots and other automated appliances. Normally, it's a boring job, but they come upon some actual killer robots. Differences are that the robots are being directed by someone else and it's set in the future (which your question doesn't seem to suggest).

Big possible match, according to [the TVTropes entry](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/Runaway) (emphasis mine), "Luther finds the Tracking Device Ramsay planted on the templates and leaves it on the toilet roll of a hospital **bathroom**. He also leaves one of his **spiderbots** which kills forensic officer Sally and a SWAT guard."

[image: German movie poster]

Spiderbot image from [this article](http://www.explore-science-fiction-movies.com/robotic-spider.html):
[image]

**Trailer** (if I'm interpreting the actions on-screen correctly, the toilet attack is in here)

Comment: Unfortunately, I've checked again that movie, and it's definitely not this one... It was definitely a short movie, and a kind of alternative/independent/small production (not a block buster of any kind). It was on an (official, not homemade/self-recorded) VHS with  a bunch of other movies, classified as "horror" (or something like that). Another short movie on that compilation was about the bombing of Hiroshima, as far as I remember (but, I was a kid, unfortunately I can't tell you much more)

Answer (score 5):

At 95 minutes, [Pulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_%281988_film%29) is a relatively short film, and it came out in 1988  so fits the timeframe.

According to the reviews and summaries, it's about an evil electromagnetic pulse that causes household appliances to come to life and attack the occupants.

Found via the TV Tropes page [Attack of the Killer Whatevers](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AttackOfTheKillerWhatEver)

Comment: Some screenshots here: http://www.horrormoviediary.net/2013/07/pulse-1988.html

Answer (score 3):

Not likely the movie you're thinking of, but the only thing coming to mind is *Maximum Overdrive*.  It's based on a Stephen King short story where devices come to life after Earth passes through the tail of a comet.

Comment: Nope, definitely not this one, though the Stephen King-like atmosphere is a common point

Comment: I don't know the Stephen King story, but the idea of domestic appliances coming to life and rebelling against humans reminds me of Clifford Simak's 1950 short story ["Skirmish"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?68356) aks "Bathe Your Bearings in Blood!".

Comment: Ow, it wasn't a Stephen King story, I'm pretty sure... Just the anguishing atmosphere makes me think about that. I don't know Simak story, maybe it's related, I'll read it

Answer (score 1):

I remember a film like this too. In particular a scene in which the pizza slicer chases a woman around a kitchen. I don't remember the spider robots being part of this same movie though.

The name of the movie is *[Don't Go To Sleep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Go_to_Sleep)* (1982).

Comment: This seems like more of a generic slasher/ghost movie than one where domestic devices try to take over.

Answer (score 1):

"Attack of the Killer Refrigerator," a 1990 10-minute short film, now something of a classic, on VHS along with *[The Hook of Woodland Heights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hook_of_Woodland_Heights)*. From [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103729/):

> A group of teenagers get drunk and abuse a hapless refrigerator. The machine then goes on a killing rampage, eating the ones who beat him up.

[image: VHS casing for Attack of the Killer Refrigerator]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you describe any scenes that match the question?  The more details you can add to confirm the match the better.

Comment: This seems like it could be just what the questioner might be looking for (or have been 5 years ago). I agree with DavidW, you should fill out the answer a bit to confirm it contains all the salient details to be the answer. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as and when for guidance to our ways, then you can [edit] to add those details.

Comment: [No bathroom attack that I can see](https://archive.org/details/Attack.of.the.Killer.Refrigerator.1990.VHSRip.DivX-HeYWooD.avi)

Answer (score -1):

I think the movie you’re referring to is “Batteries Not Included.”

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please note that the question was looking for a _horror_ short movie; I don't recall _*batteries not included_ being a horror movie, or short.  Plus the machines are aliens, not domestic devices, and there's no scene with robot spiders attacking anyone...