# Film where a vacuum cleaner attacks

Tags: story-identification, movie

There is a film circa early-mid 80s, it might have been the late 70s.

In the scene there’s a vacuum that comes out of the kitchen cupboard and attacks. I also think the vacuum used its cord to kill a person and it might also have exploded at the end of the scene.

Does anybody know this film? It wasn’t Maximum Overdrive or Pulse.

Comment: Er... Do you mean a vacuum, or a vacuum cleaner?

Comment: Partial match could be the abduction of Barry in close encountersbof the third kind. I don't think it's exactly what you described but would be good to tick it off the list... Was there something in Poltergeist with a vacuum cleaner? Not sure...

Comment: Was it a full-lrngth film? There's an episode of "Tales From The Darkside" called "Hush"; based on a short story of the same name by Zenna Henderson.https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0716948/reviews

Comment: For reference, this question was originally posted as an answer to [this previous question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121202/80s-scifi-short-movie-where-the-domestic-devices-come-to-life-and-takes-over-fr), so I'm guessing that the correct answer here isn't any of the ones posted there.

Comment: Humorous partial match with Flying High 2 / Airplane 2 where there is a cupboard on the space shuttle labelled "Danger - Vacuum" and when an incautious Robert Hays opens the cupboard a vacuum cleaner attacks him.  (Doesn't match since he survives after a brief struggle.)  However, given the movie is a series of gags based on scenes from other films, possibly suggests the original was pre 1982.

Comment: Is this stop-motion? Animated? Is it a long or short film?

Comment: Reminds me of the one where the [tire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_(2010_film)) attacks.

Comment: The vacuum in ["Mr. Mom"](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia4.giphy.com%2Fmedia%2FXtMBSR8oTlDO%2Fgiphy.gif%3Fcid%3Decf05e47clv0e318bv1l7j1sm4jdyb251und090ynbw8xc9z%26rid%3Dgiphy.gif%26ct%3Dg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fgiphy.com%2Fgifs%2Fmaudit-photoset-maudit-michael-keaton-XtMBSR8oTlDO&tbnid=jXnCIk4GAXsBJM&vet=12ahUKEwjnnZzYsJH1AhUNL6wKHRd7BngQMygFegQIARBi..i&docid=-J3AtvcWfPGyzM&w=245&h=244&q=mr%20mom%20vacuum&ved=2ahUKEwjnnZzYsJH1AhUNL6wKHRd7BngQMygFegQIARBi) attacked the baby and exploded when Michael Keaton wrestled with it.  Nobody died though.

Comment: Obviously _[Over-sexed Rugsuckers from Mars](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0200940)_ from 1989. Although I suppose it's the vacuum [getting attacked](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9wR39Ha44E).

Comment: @Spencer: It's fuzzy and only appears at night after you close your eyes.

Answer (score 6):

This could be [Runaway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runaway_(1984_American_film)), a 1984 film starring Tom Selleck.

İİRC there is a scene where household appliances (including a washing machine and hoover) attack the residents of a house.

The plot consists of Tom Selleck working as a cop trying to identify why robot appliances are attacking people.

Will try to find the clip when not on mobile if I can.

Comment: I think it is not that movie, I do not remember the scene with the vacuum cleaner

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is [*Airplane II: The Sequel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airplane_II:_The_Sequel).

There's a short sequence about 23 minutes in, in which Ted Striker is in the shuttle's galley, sees a cupboard marked ‘DANGER VACUUM’, and opens it, only to be attacked by the hose (and upholstery attachment) of a vacuum cleaner. With some effort he manages to push it back into the cupboard and close the doors.

The clip is currently available [on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71ukAH6Ny80).

That vacuum doesn't kill anyone, but later in the movie:

> one character is killed by gas, and two others die when an airlock is opened and they get <s>sucked</s> blown out into space.

Answer (score -1):

Blood sucking vacuums from mars?

I watched a b movie called that. Cant find on the internet. Just VHS video would say mid to late 80s

Comment: Are you thinking of *[Over-sexed Rugsuckers from Mars](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0200940/)*?

Comment: "*Tiny Martians use Earth as a laboratory to try out new life forms.
They return after ten million years only to find the human experiment a
complete failure. They decide to mate a human with a vacuum cleaner to
create a species that will be better at cleaning up after itself.
But a programming error by a drunk Martian sends the over-sexed
stud-vacuum cleaner on a wild rampage of raping, killing, carnage, and
overall bad manners."*

Comment: Already [mentioned in comments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/258827/film-where-a-vacuum-cleaner-attacks/280973#comment711880_258827). Apparently it doesn't really match the description